# How can I use a button that checks for a text box's information and switches forms if the value I set matches the text box's?

Tags: vb.net

So I am working on an application that requires a sign-in with information that I give to certain friends of mine, and this is basically what I need to achieve:

- I am working with Visual Basic
- There are 4 elements on the form:

  - LoginButton
  - Username
  - Password
  - HelpButton (You really don't need this at all)
- When the Login button is pressed, it will check for the information in the username and password text box if it matches the value I put in the code. For example, the login info is USER1 and PASS1 then when you press the login button it will check if USER1 is in the username text box and if PASS1 is in the password text box.

Does anyone know how you would code this in Form1.vb?

I appreciate any and all help! :)

Comment: What problem are you having doing this? Have you written any code at all? It's getting an error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use an if statement that compares the values of the textboxes to the predetermined values in code:

```
Private Sub btnLogIN_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnLogIN.Click
    If txtPassword.Text = Password And txtUserName = UserName Then
        'log in 
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("Invalid Log in")

    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Never mind! I found out with some good old research!

Use this code:

```
Private Sub LoginButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles LoginButton.Click
    If (Textboxname).Text = Nothing Then
        Call MsgBox("message", , "title")
    End If

    If UsernameBox.Text = "value" Then
        Call MsgBox("message", , "title")
    Else MsgBox("message", , "title")
    End If
End Sub
```